# Why Are the Buttons on My Calculator Web App Becoming Circles When Viewed on a Mobile Phone (iPhone 6)

Tags: html, css, web-applications, responsive-design

I decided to view my calculator web app on a mobile phone, and the square buttons all became circular, as well as the colors of the buttons all look way lighter, like totally faded out? What would cause this problem?
Here are the pictures for comparison:

- List item

[desktop screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SV4T.jpg)

[Smartphone (iPhone 6) screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0fUF.jpg)

Also why is the entire calculator not fitting on the mobile screen?
Here is the link to my CodePen:

Here is my HTML code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ziontific Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 id="heading">ZIONTIFIC CALCULATOR</h1>
        <div class="form holder">
           <form id="formone" name="calc">
          <input id="display" type="text" name="display" value=".....Get on board...." disabled contenteditable="false" >
          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="1" onClick=”calc.display.value+=1”>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="2" onClick="calc.display.value+=2">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="3" onClick="calc.display.value+=3">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="C" onClick="Resetfunction(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="<-" onClick="backspace(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="=" onClick="evaluation(this.form)">
          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="4" onClick="calc.display.value+=4">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="5" onClick="calc.display.value+=5">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="6" onClick="calc.display.value+=6">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="-" onClick="calc.display.value+='-'">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="%" onClick="calc.display.value+='%'">
          <input class="button end one" type="button" value="cos" onClick="cos_function()">
          <br>


          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="7" onClick=”calc.display.value+=7”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="8" onClick=”calc.display.value+=8”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="9" onClick=”calc.display.value+=9”>
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="*" onClick="calc.display.value+='*'">
          <input class="button n" type="button" value="n!" onClick="fact_function()">
          <input class="button sin"type="button" value="sin" onClick="sin_function()">
          <br>
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="." onClick="calc.display.value+='.'">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="0" onClick="calc.display.value+=0">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="," onClick="calc.display.value+=','">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="+" onClick="calc.display.value+='+'">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="/" onClick="calc.display.value+='/'">
          <input class="button end two" type="button" value="tan" onClick=”tan_function()”>
          <br>
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="E" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.718">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="pi" onClick="calc.display.value+=3.141">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="x^y" onClick="power_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="(" onClick="openpara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value=")" onClick="closepara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()">
          <br>
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN2" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.693">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN10" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.302">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log2E" onClick="calc.display.value+=1.442">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log10E" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.434">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="EXP" onClick="exp_function">

          </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color;
}


h1{
color: white;
}


    .container{
        background-image:   url(https://s26.postimg.org/frq6u3odl/texture-seamless-wood-3.jpg);
        position: relative;
        max-width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
        height: 650px;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        border: 0;
}
.form.holder{
   width:500px;
   height:550px;
   margin: auto;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   background-color:black;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius:10px;
   border:2px groove #333;
   box-shadow:4px 4px 2px #666666;
}

 #formone{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}  

    }
.button {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#display{
  height:60px;
  width:470px;
  color: grey;
  margin:3px;
  border:2px inset black;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  background-color:#c6c6c4;
}

.button.end.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.number.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.three{
background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.opps.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
  }


.button.number.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.opps.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}



.button.n{
  background-color: #ffff00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}



.button.sin{
  background-color: #ffff00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.end.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}


.button.third.row{
  background-color: #ef1a07;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: try `.button { border-radius: 0; }`

Comment: both screenshots look different and some of the elements are missing too.. I think you will have to restructure your design.

Comment: @HEldursi, thanks! That worked! I added the following code  to my CSS style `input, textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;}` .......now how do I get the entire calculator to fit on the mobile screen, without being cropped?

Comment: @AdarshMohan, yes, both screenshots are different....one is a **desktop** screenshot and one is a **mobile phone** screenshot...

Comment: Make the webpage responsive. or use `media queries` in css3.

Comment: @AdarshMohan, thanks for your help! Can you also checkout my other question/post about the real estate page? Thanks in advance! Cheers!